# Pull navbar list item to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble doing a simple pull-right on the last of my navbar's list items while keeping the other three items to the left. Tried a few different things, including float:right; on the list item in question. Bootstrap has a "pull-right" class, which just has float:right; within it. I've also tried float:right; on the `<a>` tag directly. Any input would be appreciated.

```html
<aside>
  <div class="container">
 <nav>
   <ul>
       {% for page in site.pages %} {% if page.title %}
    <li><a href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li><!-- This is two list items -->
    {% endif %} {% endfor %}
    <li><a href="{{ "/blog" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ "/portfolio" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">About</a></li>**<!--Trying to pull this list item to the right -->**
   </ul>
 </nav>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: try `li:last-child {position: absolute; right: 0;}`

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding the question - but are you sure putting float:right directly on the <a> doesn't work? Check [this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21509/)

Comment: I figured it out, some errors in my syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `float: right` directly on the `li` element worked.

I wouldn't recommend that though, `li` is a block element and giving it a float collapses it into something akin to `display: inline-block` which is inconsistent with the other elements and might mess things up.

How about `text-align: right`? That'll stick the text to the right edge (because it's a block element and it occupies the entire width).

Comment: No prob :) Are you looking for that to act as button, though? Because in that case the button occupies the entire width of the screen and clicking anywhere with in it will redirect you... you may want a different approach.

Comment: Embarrassing thing actually, I had a rule on the `<navbar>` tag `float: left;` that was overriding my ability to pull that last list item to the right. Once I got rid of that rule there was no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution Bro Nameth. Just make a rule inside your custom css file like this. Notice I gave the container and id of hello as well.

```
   #hello li:nth-child(3) {
text-align:right
}

ul {
list-style:none;
}
<aside>
  <div id="hello" class="container">
 <nav>
   <ul>
       {% for page in site.pages %} {% if page.title %}
    <li><a href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl        }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li><!-- This is two list items -->
    {% endif %} {% endfor %}
    <li><a href="{{ "/blog" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ "/portfolio" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">About</a></li>**<!--Trying to pull this list item to the right -->**
   </ul>
 </nav>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you Bro Montana!

Comment: Nice. I'd keep the css styling separate from your html.